# Eclipse não está reconhecendo CSS do projeto com JavaFX

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx

Meu projeto com JavaFX simplesmente parou de reconhecer meu .css e aparece o seguinte erro:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

No error log aparece o seguinte:

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.showPageRec(PageBookView.java:994)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView.showPageRec(ConsoleView.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.partClosed(PageBookView.java:809)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView.partClosed(ConsoleView.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView$4.partClosed(PageBookView.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$23.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4966)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.firePartClosed(WorkbenchPage.java:4963)
...
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Eu gostaria de poder editar o css pelo próprio eclipse...

Comment: Seu Eclipse está atualizado na última versão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu atualizei minha versão do eclipse e resolveu. Mais tarde deu o mesmo problema de novo. A solução que encontrei foi trocar de IDE ou editar o CSS na mão mesmo por documentos de edição de textos. Obrigada a todos que deram sugestões!

Answer (score 1):

Tente remover esse plugin e depois adicioná-lo novamente.
Você pode remover indo na opção:

> Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Installed

Aqui será mostrado todos os plugins instalados e um botão de remoção.